# Create xml file from java object

Tags: java, xml

1. I want to create an XML file from java 6 (it's the first time I want to try that) and I would like an example of how can I do that with DOM. I need an example showing how to build tree?
2. Can I create an EDMX file from a java object ?

Regards,
Boris

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest example of convert java object to xml is this:

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "entity")
public class Entity {

    private int age = 22;
    private String firstname = "Michael";

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge( int age ) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname( String firstname ) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( Entity.class );
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.marshal( new Entity(), System.out );
    } 
}
```

Will print to the console this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><entity><age>22</age><firstname>Michael</firstname></entity>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to serialize java objects to XML file - just feed them to [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) ! It works both ways. Code snippets [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) .

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It think you should go with `JAXB` and `JAXP`, this will make your life much easier than using DOM.....